# Can I host my main domain and a subdomain of it in 2 different hosting services

Tags: dns, subdomain, hosting, cpanel, firebase-hosting

Currently, my react web app is hosted in firebase hosting and pointed to my main domain (say ***mydomain.com***) and I need a subdomain ***sub.mydomain.com*** point to my existing PHP project in another hosting service with a C-panel.

> **Not Worked** : I added a DNS A record to sub.mydomain.com and point it to my Shared IP address located in cpanel. But my main domain also not worked after that.

Any solution to this, I know it's better if I can deploy both sites in the same domain, but for this temporary purpose, it's necessary doing this.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing complicated.

Let's say,

You will just have to add the A record of sub-domain in the DNS zone of the main domain. Make sure your main domain is using the nameserver of firebase hosting to work the main domain with firebase hosting and sub-domain with hosting service having cPanel.

After, you will have to add the main domain in cPanel, because cPanel will not allow creating the sub-domain without adding the main domain. Then create the sub-domain.

Note: As your domain uses the Nameserver of firebase hosting it shows the site content from the firebase hosting service and as you have to add the A record for the sub-domain using the IP address of the hosting service having cPanel. The sub-domain will show the site from your other service having cPanel.

You can find the Nameserver of your main domain at your domain name registrar. You can use any online tool to find the nameserver of your domain as well.

Put the comment if the above suggestion does not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the process. But firebase hosting only provides me an A record and a TXT record, where can I find the Nameservers of firebase.